# PHP post request with cURL and cookie

Tags: php, post, curl, cookies, request

I am trying to make request to a webpage which requires a login.
I successfully take the cookie with the SESSID and write it to a file with curl:

```
$username = 'xxx';
$password = 'xxxxxxx';
$url = 'http://example.com';
$cookie="cookie.txt";
$postdata = "username=$username&userpass=$password&autologin=1&userlogin=Login";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
$result = curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

Now after this I want to make a POST request to the site with the cookie so it recognizes me as logged in. It uses API that returns JSON information if you do request like:
`site.com/API/command.get(x)`  - just an example. So if you open this in the browser, it returns the JSON data.

Can anyone help me with a way, how to do this? I am new to curl.

No matter what I try, I get redirected to login page.
Tried to pass `curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);`, no success.

Comment: Post what is in `cookie.txt` please

Comment: Just having the SESSID in a cookie does not mean that you have been logged in. It only means that the server can recognize you as a client from the SESSID. You have to login also.

Comment: Hi, in the file there is info like: # Netscape HTTP Cookie File
# http://curl.haxx.se/rfc/cookie_spec.html
# This file was generated by libcurl! Edit at your own risk.

site.com FALSE / FALSE 1429265797 ZBW_SESSID

Comment: @NikolayMegdanov please provide a firefox firebug output of post and header info from a successful login post request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks guys for your hints.
How I got it working is with this code(I actually had used wrong post data):

```
$username = 'xxx';
$password = 'xxxx';
$url = 'http://example.com'; //request to the page i want the content from
$cookie="cookie.txt";

$url1 = "http://example.com/command..";

//login form action url
$postinfo = "act=login&login=$username&pass=$password";

$cookie_file_path = "cookie.txt";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path);
//set the cookie the site has for certain features, this is optional
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file_path);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-US; rv:1.7.12) Gecko/20050915 Firefox/1.0.7");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postinfo);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
//var_dump($result);

//page with the content I want to grab
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url1);
//do stuff with the info with DomDocument() etc
$html = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($html);
curl_close($ch);
```

I got this code somewhere in here(stackoverflow). Thanks to the guy that posted it! don't remember the exact name. This works like a charm !

Answer (score 2):

I find curl's cookie jar problematic so I wrote my own routine.  There are other times I need to add cookies scraped from the page.
For this `CURLOPT_HEADER` must be true.

```
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);

  $data = curl_exec($ch);
  $skip = intval(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE)); 
  $requestHeader= substr($data,0,$skip);
  $data =  substr($data,$skip);
  $e = 0;
  while(true){
    $s = strpos($requestHeader,'Set-Cookie: ',$e);
    if (!$s){break;}
    $s += 12;
    $e = strpos($requestHeader,';',$s);
    $cookie = substr($requestHeader,$s,$e-$s) ;
    $s = strpos($cookie,'=');
    $key = substr($cookie,0,$s);
    $value = substr($cookie,$s);
    $cookies[$key] = $value;
  }
```

Then to use the $cookies[]:

```
 $cookie = '';
 $show = '';
 $delim = '';
 foreach ($cookies as $k => $v){
   $cookie .= "$delim$k$v";
   $delim = '; ';
 }
```

Then use $cookie:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie );
```

When there is trouble, I often set `FOLLOWLOCATION` to false:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
```

If there is a Redirect you can see what is happening and need get cookies that are set in the Redirected URL's Response Header then `FOLLOWLOCATION` must be set to false.

When the curl URL takes you to a redirect `curl_getinfo` will get the redirect location URL.

```
$status = intval(curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE));
if ($status > 299 && $status < 400){
  $url= curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_REDIRECT_URL );
}
// update cookies, do not clear `cookies()`;
```

---

When it gets tough I uses these options to get both Response and Response Headers. The Response Header will be return in the `curl_exec()` data.  The Request Header will be return by `curl_getinfo()`

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $request);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);


$data = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)){
    $data .= 'Retreive Base Page Error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}
else {
  $info = rawurldecode(var_export(curl_getinfo($ch),true));
  $data = curl_exec($ch);
  $skip = intval(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE)); 
  $requestHeader= substr($data,0,$skip);
  $data =  substr($data,$skip);
  $filename = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
  $filename .= parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH) . '.txt';
  $fp = fopen($filename,'w');
  fwrite($fp,$info\n$data");
  fclose($fp);

  $data =  substr($data,$skip);
}
```

Both header and the HTML are stored in the file.  You can then view both HTTP Headers, the HTML and JavaScript.  Sometimes cookies are set by JavaScript document.cookie, or the page redirected with window.location, or an HTML form's submit button is clicked with JS.  In these cases it may be necessary to scrape the cookies and or redirect location from the curl data.

---

Then I use FireFox Inspector or Chrome Development Tool.

I go to the Network Tab

In FireFox I go to Settings and turn on "Enable Persistent logs"
In Chrome I click "Preserve log" on the Network Tab

Then I use the Browser to go wherever I want curl to go.

Now I can see every Request and Response including redirects and compare them with the save headers.

---

When you need the header to look exactly like the saved Browser headers:

Create an array to put the Request Header Key Values
Fill in the Request array with exactly what is in the Request header of your upload.
**EXAMPLE:**

```
$request = array();
$request[] = "Host: www.example.com";
$request[] = "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
$request[] = "User-Agent: MOT-V9mm/00.62 UP.Browser/6.2.3.4.c.1.123 (GUI) MMP/2.0";
$request[] = "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5";
$request[] = "Connection: keep-alive";
$request[] = "Cache-Control: no-cache";
$request[] = "Pragma: no-cache";
```

Add to curl:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $request);
```

---

Many times it is much easier to use a mobile version. Many times the  desktop version page requires JavaScript and the mobile version does not.  I use FireFox with user agent switcher using an old Motorola user agent to retrieve the headers and HTML.  Then I use the same user agent in curl's `HTTPHEADER`:

```
request[] = 'User-Agent: MOT-V9mm/00.62 UP.Browser/6.2.3.4.c.1.123 (GUI) MMP/2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you would try [guzzle](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)? I wrote proxy for some game engine, and i got similar problem with cookies.

**Important**: I didn't find easy way to manipulate cookies in key-value style. So, as for me, it decision closer to hack than solution. I glued cookie to string:

```
foreach ($request->cookies as $key => $cookie) {
    $cookie_str .= $key .'='.$cookie . ';
}
```

And my solution looks like this:

```php
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client([
    'headers' => [
        'Cookie' => $cookie_str
    ]
]);

$reqv = $client -> createRequest('POST', 'some_url');
$resp = $client -> send($reqv);
```